# In Italian, do you say "non andiamo d’accordo" figuratively when you are hopelessly bad at something?

Tags: idioms

> Io e la cucina **non andiamo d’accordo** su niente.

I mean, as if I and *someone else* {person} don't agree with each other?

In French, we say "la cuisine et moi, [ça fait deux](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/27576/le-japonais-et-moi-%C3%A7a-fait-deux-trois-dix-mille-etc-un-nombre-plus-grand)" with the meaning of "io e la cucina **facciamo due**".

Is this phrase "non andiamo d’accordo" (most) commonly used in Italian to express this idea?

Comment: It seems like a humorous way to express that concept, but not a standard one: more like a one-shot witticism.

Comment: @DaG In French, even if "ça fait deux" is most common, the phrasing "la cuisine et moi, **on ne s'entend pas** du tout" {we don't get along} is also used. In Italian, on the other hand, is this "non andiamo d’accordo" phrase not established well enough to be considered an idiomatic expression? Actually, I saw a similar phrase in a casual (chatting) email from a native Italian speaker.

Comment: I myself have heard it once or twice, so it may either be an uncommon idiomatic expression, or an original phrase on its way towards a larger diffusion. Hard to say. In fact, one can find some occurrences in Google Books: “io e gli ascensori non andiamo d'accordo”, “Non sono pigro, ma io e i soldi non andiamo d'accordo”, from recent translations.

Comment: I would rather say that there is no prevalent idiomatic expression used to express this concept. There are several less common ones (for instance *la cucina, [non so neanche dove sta di casa](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/S/sapere.shtml#8)*), but not a widely used one.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that the relation subject/object is somehow inverted from the English idiom: for example you could say *Cooking doesn't agree with me* in English, but *Io non vado d'accordo con la cucina* in Italian.

Comment: @DenisNardin Hi. I suppose in everyday conversation you get to hear "A et B, ça fait deux" or "A et B, on ne s'entend pas" in French. How would you *personally* convert this idea into Italian?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens I don't have a preferred expression. Probably some variation of the proposals in Jack Kirby's answer and Federico's comment (e.g. *Io e la cucina non abbiamo niente a che fare*).

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments of the question, I also think this is not a common expression to say that kind of thing. A proper way to tell someone that a person is hopelessy bad at something could be:

> "Mario e la cucina sono due mondi a parte."
>
> "Io e la cucina siamo due mondi a parte."

This figuratively means that the person bad at something and that some activity live in two different worlds distant by each other.

Comment: Thanks, Jack. I'd understand what this means and I don't deny someone uses it, but it doesn't strike me as so much more idiomatic than the phrase asked about by the OP. Since these things depend a lot on the speaker's age, geographical provenience and so on, would you mind offering some source (an excerpt from a book about idioms, examples from Italian authors...)?

Comment: I know these are not authoritative sources, but the example "Io e la cucina siamo due mondi a parte" can be found in these (and other) websites: http://www.lefunkymamas.com/mmmousse-al-cioccolato/, https://gialloecucina.wordpress.com/2015/06/02/oggi-parliamo-con-giacomo-toma/.

Comment: "Io e la matematica non andiamo d'accordo" is quite common indeed.